# Ошибки дампа MySQL

Tags: mysql

Залил БД(mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.33) на сайт, подправил через CMS кое-какие тесты, сделал дамп, а в нем какие-то непонятные вставки(см. скрин). В самой БД все корректно, но mysqldump бьет дампы, что делать?[image: непонятные символы]

Comment: Битый дамп, чего тут думать...

Comment: @Akina mysqldump  бьет все дампы в одном и том же месте, что с этим можно сделать? В системе все обновлено до последних версий.

Comment: В одном месте - это в смысле смещения в файле дампа, или на месте одной и той же записи одной и той же таблицы? Попробуй дампить "по частям".

Comment: @Akina по частям бьет тоже, смещения одинаковые для частичных дампов и разные, если сравнивать целую БД и частичную.

Answer (score 0):

Виновником оказался ftp-клиент.